# Android Studio: Why am i getting multi dex error on brand new Google Maps API project?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-multidex

I'm relatively new to Android programming and I am trying to create a Google Maps project. I used the template option in Android Studio, and I added the key for the API.

I haven't added any of my own code and left the template code as is because I just wanted to run the code and see what it looks like, however, I keep getting a multi dex error when I try to run this on the emulator causing the build to fail. It's weird to me that I am getting this error because I haven't added ANY code at all and am using what the Google Maps template has from Android Studio.

Anyone know why this error shows up on a brand new project? The error I see is pasted below.

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Your probably compiling all of the play-services API's using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'... Now we can selectively compile API's to avoid dex limit of 64K. For Google Maps use com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0...

Comment: ^ above comment worked like a charm. thanks.

Comment: Funny even google screws up the DEX limit, which I never understood why they can't fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as quoted below:

> Your probably compiling all of the play-services API's using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'... Now we can selectively compile API's to avoid dex limit of 64K. For Google Maps use com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0... – Loki Jul 1 at 19:01

Answer from Loki worked and was very simple to do.

Answer (score 2):

[setting up google play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Go through this link just add the dependencies which you want in your application.
This will prevent 64k exceeding error.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

For those who tried all the above methods and failed. Try changing the mini sdk version to 21 in the build.gradile file. For me it was on 16 and when I changed it to 21 the multidex error was gone for good.

> `minSdkVersion 21`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you currently have a high number of methods. There can only be 65536 methods for dex. You can try enabling multiDex by editing your build.gradle file.

```
android {
          //stuff

defaultConfig {
    ...

       // Enable multiDex support. 
       multiDexEnabled true
    }

}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Also, oops as the poster above mentioned in your manifest you also need to add that you are using the multidex class from the multidex support library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.dexapp">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.try.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Note: Visit https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html for more info.

Comment: Multidex sucks and is fraught with runtime errors, stay away from this!

Answer (score 0):

Set property multiDexEnabled to true in defaultConfig. This error occurs when method references increase the limit of 65k. Check Google Play Service APIs.

```
    android{
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }
```

Here is a good source to get started with [Google Maps Android API](https://www.beginnersheap.com/google-maps-android-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the dependencies as suggested by Loki and it works.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
}
```